# What image filter or transformation can produce this result?

Tags: python, image, opencv, filter

I am trying to produce this final image

[image]

from this original image

[image]

I tried with erosions, dilations and setting brightness/contrast, but I am not able to get a result similar to this. Specifically, I can not get a single grey pixel to generate several pixels around it, as is the case in the above image.

Any advice ?

Comment: try a convolution with a square matrix that holds values between 0 and 1 like `0.5`. This is basically a dilation, but will produce grey pixels around it. Basically between a gaussian blur and a dilation

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand what you want. But here is one attempt to stretch the dynamic range of intensities using Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image 
img = cv2.imread('white_spots.png')

# stretch dynamic range
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255))

# save result
cv2.imwrite('white_spots_stretched.png', result)

# Display result
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for. If you look closely in the final image, where there was originally a single grey pixel, it is now replaced by 4-5 pixels of different greys.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want.  If you need more gray pixels nearby, then simply blur the image and possibly stretch the contrast.